# Can not connect to WebHDFS by port 14000 in Cloudera Manager

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, webhdfs

I have a Cloudera (the version is `cdh6.2.0`) cluster and every components(HDFS, HIVE etc.) worked well. However, recently I want to connect to WebHDFS, I found the port(14000) was not running at all, by executing command `netstat -antpl|grep 14000` on the `NameNode`.

I have confirmed the WebHDFS was enabled in Cloudera Manager and it was used `14000` port by default.

[image]

Besides, I also tried `50070` port, it didn't listen either. I also tried `curl`:

```
curl -i "http://localhost:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/user.name=cloudera&op=GETFILESTATUS"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 14000: Connection refused
```

I appreciate for any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using `9870` port instead.

I found the version of my Hadoop is 3.0, and it is listening with `9870` but not the `50070` for `dfs.namenode.http-address`.
[image]

As for `14000`, it is may used for `HTTPS` REST.
[image]

Reference:
https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Cannot-connect-to-webhdfs/td-p/34830

Comment: hdfs getconf -confKey dfs.namenode.http-address